# Factory method 'redisConnectionFactory' threw exception; Host name must not be null or empty

Tags: spring-data-redis

i have implemented redis configuration in my spring boot project using gradle. But when i run the project i'm getting the error saying bean initialization failed.

Following is my config file.

```
package com.nsdlegov.vsp.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;
import org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer;
import org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.StringRedisSerializer;


@Configuration
public class RedisNewConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory() {

        RedisStandaloneConfiguration serverConfig = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(environment.getProperty("spring.redis.master"), 6379);

        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(serverConfig);

    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,SchemeMaster> redisTemplateSchemeMaster(){

        RedisTemplate<String,SchemeMaster> template= new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());  
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(SchemeMaster.class)); 
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(SchemeMaster.class));

        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,PincodeMaster> redisTemplatePincodeMaster() {
        RedisTemplate<String, PincodeMaster> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(PincodeMaster.class));
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(PincodeMaster.class));
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String,IfscMaster> redisTemplateIfscMaster() {
        RedisTemplate<String, IfscMaster> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory());
        template.setEnableTransactionSupport(true);
        template.setHashKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setHashValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(IfscMaster.class));
        template.setKeySerializer(new StringRedisSerializer());
        template.setValueSerializer(new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer<>(IfscMaster.class));
        return template;
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file :

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.1.1.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


ext['springCloudVersion'] = 'Finchley.SR1'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'io.lettuce:lettuce-core:5.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.data:spring-data-redis:2.1.1.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.postgresql:postgresql:42.2.5'
    compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1.1'
    compile 'org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:2.3.0.1'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.3.7.Final'
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.cloud', name: 'spring-cloud-starter-config', version:'2.0.1.RELEASE'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

group = 'com.nsdlegov.vsp'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
description = 'vsp-redis-service'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}
```

Im getting following error:

```
aused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisConnectionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/nsdlegov/vsp/config/RedisNewConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory]: Factory method 'redisConnectionFactory' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Host name must not be null or empty!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:456) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$128/46941357.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:273) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1237) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1164) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:857) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Firstly the project was in maven. But recently i have converted it to gradle project. In maven it was running fine, But in gradle it is giving me same error.

Please help me and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing spring.redis.url and use spring.redis.host instead?
I've done it and I fixed the error.